# Formatting a string number

Tags: c#, string, format, currency

I want to format a string number. For example:

```
double number="118176";
```

It should look like 1181.71 or 1181,71.
I couldn't find any format type. I tried some of format types as `ToString("#,0")` but it didn't work.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: which programming language are you using ?

Comment: Double variable won't accept a string.
Which language are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "format a string"? You generally *parse* a string or *format* a number. It sounds like you might want to parse, manipulate, then format...

Comment: Why exactly should the parse of `"118176"` end up with `1181.71`? The `6` turns into a `1` for what reason?

Comment: By the way, `double number="118176";` will not compile. If you post an example, please post something that is correct code.

Comment: I use c# in VS2010.
Here is the sample of my code;
price.InnerHtml += nodeFareList.SelectSingleNode("GenQuoteDetails/TotAmt").InnerText;
The string value 118176. But i want to format it as "1181.76". And i tried;
price.InnerHtml += Convert.ToDouble(nodeFareList.SelectSingleNode("GenQuoteDetails/TotAmt").InnerTe‌​xt).ToString("#,#");
There must be something for ToString() method

Comment: If always the last two numbers are the decimal fraction you can do it with substrings, like:
`var d = "118176";`
`var e = string.Format( "{0}.{1}", d.Substring( 0, d.Length - 2 ), d.Substring( d.Length - 2 ) );`
*Note* I didn't test it, i'm not at home but that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: a `double` variable can not take a string. But that aside, something like this should help:

```
double number = 1181.76;
string output = String.Format("{0:d2}", number);
```

This takes the number and creates a string from it using the decimal number format with 2 decimal places.

What you didn't say is why you expect the integer `118176` to magically turn into a double with two decimals? The only way would be

```
double number = 118176;
string output = String.Format("{0:d2}", number / 100.0);
```

**EDIT**
Doing what you describe in your comment is a bit more complex:

```
string priceString = nodeFareList.SelectSingleNode("GenQuoteDetails/TotAmt").InnerText; 
double priceDouble = Convert.ToDouble(priceString) / 100.0;
price.InnerHtml += String.Format("{0:c}", priceDouble);
```

This converts the number in `priceDouble` to a string with the value formatted like a currency. If you do not want the currency symbol, use the following:

```
price.InnerHtml += String.Format("{0:d2}", priceDouble);
```

Comment: Here is the sample of my code;
price.InnerHtml += nodeFareList.SelectSingleNode("GenQuoteDetails/TotAmt").InnerText;
The string value 118176. But i want to format it as "1181.76". And i tried;
price.InnerHtml += Convert.ToDouble(nodeFareList.SelectSingleNode("GenQuoteDetails/TotAmt").InnerText).ToString("#,#");
There must be something for ToString() method.

Comment: No. A string is always a string. It doesn't matter whether it contains numbers or not. What you need to do is convert the string to a numeric type before. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See Fixed-point on this page (assuming .net): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

You'll have to divide by 100 first though.

Answer (score 0):

Use can refer the below code in case of Java.

1) First define the Decimal Format instance.

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("####.##");

2) Then pass the decimal value to the 'format' method

String dummyString = decimalFormat.format(pressureValue).toString()

where pressureValue - Decimal number

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you are looking for is this:

```
String.Format("{0:0,0.0}", 12345.67);     
String.Format("{0:0,0}", 12345.67);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for details.